# Sharing Bluetooth Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: bluetooth

I know "teleport" will work between two Macs, but is there a way to share a keyboard and mouse between a Mac Mini and an older Dell PC? I'm asking because I received a Mac Mini and iPad for Christmas but still need the PC until I get familiar with the Apples and start tranfering stuff to them. I know just enough about computers to be dangerous, viz-- I just bought a Logitec MX 5500 Desktop with software for the PC with a USB Bluetooth dongle and it does work with the Mac Mini, but I didn't realize you cannot pair with more than one computer even if the other is off.

My son says I can do it with something called a Bluetooth KVM, is this true?

I can use the same monitor because it has both digital and analog inputs and is easily switchable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a local network you can use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to share Bluetooth mice and keyboards with up to 5 computers.

> Synergy lets you easily share your mouse and keyboard between multiple
>   computers on your desk, and it's Free and Open Source. Just move your
>   mouse off the edge of one computer's screen on to another. You can
>   even share all of your clipboards. All you need is a network
>   connection. Synergy is cross-platform (works on Windows, Mac OS X and
>   Linux).

Here is a good implementation for Mac and Linux: http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a monitor for each, you can control both with Synergy over your network.

Here's a good example.
http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/how-to-configure-synergy-in-six-steps/

You'd use one keyboard and mouse connected to your PC, and then via Synergy when you move your mouse off the PC monitor, it will change focus to the Mac. It's a good setup if you've got the monitors.

If you haven't got a second monitor, give VNC a shot. You would use "Screen Sharing" from the mac mini, and connect with WinVNC from your Dell. A window will appear that has your mac's desktop on it.

If you can't be bothered with VNC, use LogMeIn Free. https://secure.logmein.com/
Works for PC/Mac, and you can access it from anywhere in the world!